# Unable to solve Java form of jdbc query with variables

Tags: jdbc

sql3 =  "select  avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) from(select ("+baseParam+"/"+denom+"))as eff from ras)as s"; This is query whose output i want.
When i execute the code i get the error stating check your mysql version for syntax. I am using string to store the name of columns. I want to find the efficienccy with respect to 2000 Job_Render i.e. efficiency for each job_render. But what i get is total efficiency of all job_render. when i use the sql syntax with their direct column names. I have commented that query too for the reference. I want to find efficiency of each job render with respect to their 2000 JOBID. Bottom line is i want to find efficiency of 2000 JOBID each whose formula is Job_Render/LC_Final+LC_Preview. I have stored Job_Render in String baseParam and sum of both LC in String Denom. Please help me out.

```
public class Efficiency {

     static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
     static final String DB_USER = "root";
     static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
     static final String dbName = "raas";



    public static void main(String[] args)   {

        try{
            effFunc();
        }


        catch (Exception q){
            q.getMessage();
        }


    }
    static void effFunc() throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{

            Connection conn = null;


            // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

            // STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION + dbName, DB_USER,
                    DB_PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
            String baseParam;
            //String[] subParam ;
            baseParam= "Job_Render";

            String sql3="";
            String denom="";

            final String[] COL={ "LC_Final","LC_Preview"};
            denom = "(" + COL[0] + "+" + COL[1] + ")";
            Statement stmt = null;

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

    //  sql3 =  "select 'Efficiency' Field,avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) from(select (Job_Render/(LC_Final+LC_Preview))as eff from ras)as s";


sql3 =  "select  avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) from(select ("+baseParam+"/"+denom+"))as eff from ras)as s";


            System.out.println(sql3);
//          
            try{
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql3);

            //System.out.println(res);


    while(res.next()){

//      String JobID = res.getString("JobID");
//      System.out.println("Job ID : " + JobID);
        String col1 = res.getString(1);
        System.out.println(col1);
        double avg = res.getDouble(2);
        System.out.println("Average of eff is:"+avg);
        double min = res.getDouble(3);
        System.out.println("Min of eff is:"+min);
        double max = res.getDouble(4);
        System.out.println("Max of eff is:"+max);


    }}
                 catch(Exception e){
                     e.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }



}}
```

Comment: And when you run that select in your database do you get a different result?

Comment: @Elliot Frisch Yes when i run the same query through mysql workbench it runs perfectly. It does not work with jdbc

Comment: Post your JDBC code.

Comment: i changed the body with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs the query `sql1` which is the empty string,

```
String sql1="";
// sql1 = "select * from raas.jobs";
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql1); // sql1 = ""
```

should be

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql3);
```

**Edit**

Then to get the value(s)

```
String col1 = res.getString(1);
double avg = res.getDouble(2);
double min = res.getDouble(3);
double max = res.getDouble(4);
```

Comment: this is output i get com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet@27bc2616, instead of the value for eff, i tried this but still i dont get the output jdbc  what i get from mysql workbench

Comment: @DhruvSheth Edited. `ResultSet.toString()` does not fetch your data, nor does it override `Object.toString()`.

Comment: i want to run these query sql3 = "select  avg(eff),min(eff),max(eff) from(select ("+baseParam+"/"+denom+"))as eff from ras)as s"; which is minor modification of the previous query, but i get syntax error

Comment: @ElliotFrisch i have added a modified query as i want to find efficiency of each job render present in the table not the whole efficiency of all job renders together as there are more than 2000 job_render in the table. I am confused here what to do

Comment: @Dhruv Post another question. And you want to get 2000 rows?

Comment: i had modified the question.